# How to set width of grid column based on contents, text and child columns

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4.2

I have tried using `forceFit:true` and giving `flex:1` to all the columns. But child columns width is only getting set not the parent column's based on the text. 
Calling `autoSize()` on the column is returning cannot find method `getWidth() of undefined` How to do set width of the total grouped column and the cell width based on this width ?

Comment: Can you showcase your attempts in a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor)?

Answer (score 0):

The child columns have the correct width and autosizing of the parent fails?
In that case I'd iterate over the children and set the width manually as the sum of the children + possible margins/borders.

I'm not sure if there might be a better way to have this done automatically by the framework. For that we'd definitely need to see an example code snippet.
As mentioned by @scebotari66, preferrably in the form of a Sencha fiddle.